# MYSQL modify column fields based on another column fields

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have such table

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       Name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         x        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ..         |         x        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          N          |         x        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I need to change name fields to "z" for IDs between 30 and 100.
Is there any way to use a loop or a while condition instead of doing this:

```
UPDATE table
SET Name = 'z'
WHERE ID = 30
OR ID = 31
OR ID = 32
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply specify that in the where clause

```
WHERE ID >= 30 AND ID <= 100
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `BETWEEN` here:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Name = 'z'
WHERE ID BETWEEN 30 AND 100;
```